# Could we add ajax requests disallow in robots.txt in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, include, robots.txt, security.txt

My question is that could we add ajax requests disallow in robots.txt in codeigniter
And is that compulsory to add robots.txt file in home directory or we place it in views with defined routes